# InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: e is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I tried to deploy a react app by npm start, then I got the error:

```
InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: e is undefined
./node_modules/jwt-decode/build/jwt-decode.esm.js
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/lib/index.js:9

   6 |     this.message = message;
   7 | }
   8 | 
>  9 | InvalidTokenError.prototype = new Error();
  10 | InvalidTokenError.prototype.name = "InvalidTokenError";
  11 | 
  12 | export default function(token, options) {

__webpack_require__
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

1
http://localhost:3000/miniflix/static/js/main.chunk.js:1188:18
__webpack_require__
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

checkDeferredModules
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:45

  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 

webpackJsonpCallback
/home/pc/Documents/video_streaming/miniflix/webpack/bootstrap:32

  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
```

It says there is something wrong with the index.js file which I got here:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Upload from './components/Upload';
import Display from './components/Display';
import Callback from './components/Callback';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { requireAuth } from './utils/AuthService';

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Display}/>
        <Route path="/upload" component={Upload} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path="/callback" component={Callback} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
reportWebVitals()
```

I don't see any error here any thing at line 9 as there are no code there on that line.
The previous line is an import statement and the line after is the start of a const. So maybe there is some weird issue here. I tried whole morning no success.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Post the code that you used for the jwt-decode, check the argument that you're supplying and make sure that its a valid token.  You can jwt.io and check it.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).